# How to send AWS SNS mobile SMS messages based on date stored in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I have a certain use case in my application, for which I have to build an appointment booking system. It would save appointment details into a DynamoDB table, which would have information regarding the day of the appointment and the mobile number of the user. The system should send reminder SMS alerts to the user, a day before the appointment date. THere's also a status attribute in the DB table, which should change to 'TODAY' when the appointment date arrives.

How should I architect this system, to successfully implement these use cases. What should be the architectural approach to automate this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to approach this would be having a Lambda that runs on a timer [using CloudWatch cron event trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) that [scans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property) or [queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property) the DynamoDB table for values that have a date applicable for an SMS alert, and then sends the alerts accordingly using [SNS publish to SMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#publish-property) (note the links to the SDK are for javascript, but these functions are supported in other languages as well)

Comment: Should I use the lambda to directly access the dynamoDB table, using IAM?
As this [source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-create-an-aws-iam-policy-to-grant-aws-lambda-access-to-an-amazon-dynamodb-table/) suggests.

But is there a way to optimize the SCAN operation? As a number of attributes have to be checked for a record to be eligible for SNS notification.
1. There's one day left for the appointment date.
2. The status attribute of the appointment record is not equal to canceled.

Comment: Yes, you should call DynamoDB scan using a Lambda with the correct IAM permissions (you can set this easily through the lambda console). Using scan is a good candidate here, scan with multiple filters (one day left, status attribute). Scan isn't as efficient as query but in your scenario you have to scan, unless you setup your DB to be as "best wishes" suggested, and have a "notifyOn" index that you can query on (query where notifyOn = todaysDate && status != canceled)

Comment: I do have flexibility with the DB schema. So is there a possible way to structure the db around these attributes which could result in a query operation rather than a scan?
Because the table would contain appointments, therefore the table size will keep on growing day after day. Performing scans on the table daily would waste a lot of provisioned capacity in the long run as it will be unnecessarily scanning already passed appointments(whose status == done).

Comment: @RohanMehto did you check my answer? you will not have to use scan there.

Comment: Yes exactly, if you have flexibility with the schema then use query as suggested by "best wishes", it would be a lot more efficient

Answer (score 1):

You can take the below approach to solve the use-case

1. Database schema

```
| pk        |    sk      |     notifyOn    |  notificationStatus | 
| user1     | uuid1234   |     12-5-3019   |  Pending            | some other metadata
| user1     | uuid2345   |     12-5-2018   |  done               | some other metadata
| user2     | uuid2645   |     12-5-2028   |  Pending               | some other metadata
...

There is a GSI created with notifyOn as primary Key and sk as secondary Key
```

For notification part you can setup cloudwatch alert which triggers a lambda function. In the lambda function you can list all the users that should be notified today and send out notification to all the users.

Based on your use-case and scale you can do further optimizations like

1. Instead of having one lambda function sending all the notifications, just put the sk in some sqs which another lambda function picks up and send out notification. This will solve issues like

   a. throttling the writes on dyanmodb table.

   b. throttling other resources that you might be using for sending notifications.

   c. Since lambda execution times are capped at 15 mins, you may run into problems while sending too many notifications.

Comment: Just FYI, unless you're sending millions of notifications, you will never hit the 15 minute cap.